# Reload UITableView To Contain Newly inserted Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a SecondViewController as sliding panel which has a UITableView and populates it with NSArray data returned from "getnotes" function from ViewController.Running for the first time it gets all the data but when new data is inserted the UITableView does not update though the NSArray "n" contains new data.

here is the SecondViewController.h-

```
     #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
     @interface SecondViewController:UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
     {
       NSArray *n;

      }
     @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
     -(void)gets;
     @end
```

Here is the SecondViewController.m-

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface SecondViewController ()


@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self gets];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma Table View Methods

-(void)gets{

ViewController *dba=[[ViewController alloc]init];
n = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dba getnotes]];
 
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section{

if(n==nil)return 0;

return n.count;

   }
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     static NSString *cellID=@"cellID";
     UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
     if(cell==nil){
           cell=[[UITableViewCell  alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellID];
                  }

    NSDictionary * res =[n objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    

    cell.textLabel.text=[res objectForKey:@"NoteText"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,[res   objectForKey:@"NoteDate"]];
    return cell;
   }


  @end
```

Where is the problem?

#### UPDATE:  okay..I dont know if its the right way or wrong but I called the gets function and then reloaded the tableview inside viewWillAppear method and it worked :)

Comment: How you are showing `SecondViewController` from `ViewController`?

Comment: generate a Notification for that

Comment: the secondviewcontroller is a half sliding panel...the one like facebook in mobile. @Akhhilrajtr

Answer (score 1):

Simple, After inserting new data in the array just call `[tableview reloadData]`

Comment: -(void)gets{
 
    ViewController *dba=[[ViewController alloc]init];
    n = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dba getnotes]];                                
    [self.tableview reloadData];
    NSLog(@" array i got : %@",n);
}     ...it does not work

Comment: what does the log print? is it having the objects you require to show?

Comment: yap the log prints the array with new data

Comment: Please check if your data source or delegate is connected, if not then, 
`self.tableView.datasource = self` and `self.tableView.delegate = self`

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't getting any data at all, I'm thinking that you need to set the dataSourceDelegate of your table view. You may be doing that already in IB, but we can't see it in the code.

It also doesn't matter that much, but your tableView outlet can be (weak).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the tableview data source and delegate like so. Good place to do this would be in the viewDidLoad method:

```
@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tabelview.dataSource = self
    tableview.delegate = self

    [self gets];
}
```